# How to Submit on form id with javascript function?

Tags: javascript

Usually i do:

```
onclick="myFunction()"
```

on my submit button, but what i want to do now on html is

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" id="myTextBox" required> <!-- we're gonna use this id: myTextBox because we're using the getElementById() -->
<input type="submit" value="Click Me"> <!-- we call the function here -->
</form>
```

on JS

```
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = validateBarForm;
    function validateBarForm() {

        var myValue = document.getElementById('myTextBox').value; // inside the getElementById, which element we want to get? 
        if (myValue.length === 0) {
            alert('Please enter a real value in the TextBox');
            return;
        }
```

but it doesn't work? how can i also filter whitespace or blank not using required?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Are you seeing the alert? Have you checked the value of `myValue`? Are you seeing any errors in your console? Is it submitting the form even when the value is invalid?

Comment: "*but it doesn't work?*" Expedite the process by at least offering people exactly *what doesn't work*. I can't imagine many instances in life where you could get away with simply stating *it doesn't work* without the immediate reply of "*Well, what doesn't work?*"

Comment: I mean the function validateBarForm() is not working.

Comment: @GlendonPhilippBaculio You have to tell us what "not working" means. For all we know, it means it isn't sending my grandmother an email. You need to define what it *should* be doing vs. what it *is* doing.

Comment: @MikeC When I do not put anything on textbox or space if it is submitted, it will alert, but the function don't work, it doesnt alert here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/glendonphilippbaculio/09z18ysL/

Comment: Use the onsubmit event of your form instead and return true or false from your handler to say whether it's been successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = validateBarForm;
function validateBarForm() {

    var myValue = document.getElementById('myTextBox').value; // inside the getElementById, which element we want to get? 
    if (myValue.toString().trim().length === 0) {
        alert('Please enter a real value in the TextBox');
        return false;
    }
```

Edit1
I apologize for I did not explain. Below I am explaining the change.
I just trimmed the string value of input so that any whitespaces are removed. Thereafter we can safely check length of the input data to 0. Also in case of alert, i.e. when input is not correct after alert we should return false so that the form doesn't submits.

In case when function is called inline, like onclick="validateBarForm();" it should correctly be used with return statement like onclick="return validateBarForm();" so that if function returns false, then the form submit action is not triggered.

Comment: Please explain what you changed and why it was necessary, don't just dump code with no explanation.

Comment: I want to put the funnction on form id="myForm" , it doesn't work for me. I can do that if i put it on button, just wondering, maybe action=""?

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
<form id="myForm" action="#">
<input type="text" id="myTextBox" required> 
<input type="submit" value="Click Me" onclick="validateBarForm()">
</form>
    <script>
    function validateBarForm() {
         var myvalue = document.getElementById("myTextBox").value;
        if(myvalue.length === 0){
            alert("Please enter a real value in the TextBox");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    </script>
```

OR,Use this code :

```
<form id="myForm" action="#">
<input type="text" id="myTextBox" required oninvalid="alert('Please enter a real value in the TextBox')"> 
<input type="submit" value="Click Me">
</form>
```